# URL takes auto spacing when it's used in inline CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have faced a problem. I have used wp get_the_post_thumbnail_url() in inline CSS, but it's not working properly. URL takes spaces by removed slashes.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                            $startnext_features_box_markup .='
                            <div class="single-repair-services" style="background-image: url("'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().'");">';
```

**Result showing**
[image]

Comment: Your code snippet only shows how you assign this to a variable - we have no idea what happens with the content of that variable afterwards. It probably gets send through one of the WP functions used to “escape” content for different contexts, or send through a filter manipulating it … impossible for us to tell, because you have given way too little context here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this edited code

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

    $startnext_features_box_markup .='
    <div class="single-repair-services" style="background-image: url(\''.$image.'\');">';
```